# Why does application freeze after a while?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, charts, ui-thread

I am making SCADA screens (c# wpf). I have a lot animations / textbox & label changes etc. But main problem is about my chart(Winform chart). I have to update that every 2 seconds(It has 8 lines). So it makes ui thread unresponsive after a while.

**What can I do for a faster UI thread ?**

```
private static BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker; 
private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };

            backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;   
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;   
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;


        while (counter >= 1)
        {
            i++;

            //CHECK FOR CANCELLATION FIRST
            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                //CANCEL
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                simulateHeavyJob();
                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
    } 
private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){            
 Random x = new Random();
        int ajn = x.Next(0, 100);
        if (Randıman0.active)
        {

            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[0].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn-5);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[0].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[0].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }
        if (Randıman1.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[1].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn+5); 

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[1].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[1].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman2.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[2].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn+10);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[2].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[2].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman3.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[3].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn-10);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[3].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[3].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman4.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[4].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn+20);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[4].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[4].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman5.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[5].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn-20);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[5].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[5].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman6.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[6].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn+15);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[6].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[6].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        if (Randıman7.active)
        {
            cpuChart.Series[Makineler[7].isim].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, ajn-15);

            if (cpuChart.Series[Makineler[7].isim].Points.Count > 1800)
                cpuChart.Series[Makineler[7].isim].Points.RemoveAt(0);

        }


    }
    private void simulateHeavyJob()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            /*
            display("You have Cancelled");*/
        }
        else
        {
           // display("Work completed successfully");
        }
    }
```

also my chart sliding left every one minutes by:

```
 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { cpuChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate(); });
 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { cpuChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate(); });
```

Comment: You do have a lot of work inside the ProgressChanged. Which was my first point to check. But not nearly 2 seconds worth, so: any other Invoke/Background activity going on?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually i have a lot invokes but i don't run them. because only chart freezing the application in 1-1,5 hour . So if i run them it will be harder

Comment: It looks like your while loop there is infinite, and tight

Comment: @Menahem these random variables are temporary , i will put factory datas instead of them . It should be infinite already , because client will watch that 7/24

Comment: What im pointing out is that if the worker gets cancelled, the loop turns into a while(true) cpu hog

Comment: Yes, Cancellation looks broken but that should not be the core issue here.

Comment: The code you provided looks OK, but maybe the chart library has problems. Or it is in some code we can't see. Add a tag for the charting lib.

Comment: @HenkHolterman System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting // Does Winformhost make problem on wpf? I think ms chart drawing every datas from starting again and again. i mean if there are 200 datas on chart, when i add 201. data , chart deleting all of them and creating with 201 datas. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: "freezing the application in 1-1,5 hour" sounds like a memory leak. Learn to use a memory profiler. You need to know what is consuming your memory.

Comment: Alternatively, scan the chart docs for tips about usage.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i changed my line type from spline to fastline . everything is fine . thanks anyway